# compare 2 object arrays and replace object by id

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, lodash

I have a multidimensional object array that I need to update by comparing to an object array. I flattened out the multidimensional array and did a nested for each loop. I am getting duplicate results and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

```js
const newSections = [[{"id":9141118,"name":"cxz","qtr":"12/2016","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"593f35e7-c5b4-4c79-b4b8-0cc34dfd76a4"},{"id":9143204,"name":"cxz","qtr":"03/2017","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"9785f527-0c1f-414f-bd6b-9416da90a24f"}],[{"id":9141118,"name":" xzcxz","qtr":"12/2016","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"b6a78cf9-0de1-4465-bf7b-02b221330fcb"},{"id":9143204,"name":" xzcxz","qtr":"03/2017","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"9ef10b9b-b143-48a2-8e4f-fc2fdad4788b"}]]

const section = [{"id":9141118,"name":"cxz","qtr":"12/2016","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":"32","fut":0,"con":0,"tot":32,"storeTot":1,"variance":31,"uid":"593f35e7-c5b4-4c79-b4b8-0cc34dfd76a4"},{"id":9143204,"name":"cxz","qtr":"03/2017","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"9785f527-0c1f-414f-bd6b-9416da90a24f"}]

  let myNewArray = [].concat.apply([], newSections)
    let result = []
    _.each(myNewArray, item => {
      _.each(section, sec => {
        if (item.uid === sec.uid) result.push(sec)
        else result.push(item)
      })
    })

    console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: For each element in `myNewArray` you are comparing with `section` array element and inseting into result. My guess is you need to revisit the logic and check `if (item.uid === sec.uid) result.push(sec)
        else result.push(item)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to avoid a nested loop (and that solves your duplication bug):

```js
const newSections = [[{"id":9141118,"name":"cxz","qtr":"12/2016","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"593f35e7-c5b4-4c79-b4b8-0cc34dfd76a4"},{"id":9143204,"name":"cxz","qtr":"03/2017","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"9785f527-0c1f-414f-bd6b-9416da90a24f"}],[{"id":9141118,"name":" xzcxz","qtr":"12/2016","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"b6a78cf9-0de1-4465-bf7b-02b221330fcb"},{"id":9143204,"name":" xzcxz","qtr":"03/2017","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"9ef10b9b-b143-48a2-8e4f-fc2fdad4788b"}]]

const section = [{"id":9141118,"name":"cxz","qtr":"12/2016","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":"32","fut":0,"con":0,"tot":32,"storeTot":1,"variance":31,"uid":"593f35e7-c5b4-4c79-b4b8-0cc34dfd76a4"},{"id":9143204,"name":"cxz","qtr":"03/2017","min":0,"max":0,"occ":0,"mod":0,"fv":0,"uc":0,"vdl":0,"fut":0,"con":0,"tot":0,"storeTot":1,"variance":-1,"uid":"9785f527-0c1f-414f-bd6b-9416da90a24f"}]

let myNewArray = [].concat.apply([], newSections)
let result = []
_.each(myNewArray, item => {
  let newItem = section.find((sec) => item.uid === sec.uid)
  
  result.push(newItem || item)
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a logic error I think, you are loading elements of both array into your result array. you should skip pushing  if (item.uid === sec.uid) result.push(sec) if ID matches.

Comment: what do you suggest